# Ajax content not loading in IE throws 'error on page - access is denied' error but works fine on server

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer-8, intranet

I made a tool for my organization which loads html pages into one main html file(through AJAX) on choosing an option from a select list. Each selection loads a different html file.

Things looked good when I tested it from home. When I opened it through IE8 from office (no other browser is allowed - plain stupid) all hell broke loose. First it messed up the layout reason being the organization's intranet. I had to use,

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
```

This solved the layout problem still the Ajax won't load. Which is the very basic thing for this tool to work. I tried using Msxml2.XMLHTTP / Microsoft.XMLHTTP instead of XMLHttpRequest - it wouldn't work. Would someone be kind enough to help me with this? Here's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var loadedobjects = ""
    var rootdomain = "http://" + window.location.hostname

    function ajaxpage(url, containerid) {
        var page_request = false

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) // if Mozilla, Safari etc
            page_request = new XMLHttpRequest()
        else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // if IE
            try {
                page_request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")
            } 
            catch (e) {
                try {
                    page_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
                }
                catch (e) {}
            } 
        }
        else
            return false

        page_request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            loadpage(page_request, containerid)
        }

        page_request.open('GET', url, true)
        page_request.send(null)
    }

    function loadpage(page_request, containerid) {
        if (page_request.readyState == 4 && 
            (page_request.status == 200 || window.location.href.indexOf("http") == -1))
            document.getElementById(containerid).innerHTML=page_request.responseText
    }

    function loadobjs() {
        if (!document.getElementById)
            return
        for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            var file = arguments[i]
            var fileref = ""
            if (loadedobjects.indexOf(file) == -1) { // Check to see if this object has not already been added to page before proceeding
                if (file.indexOf(".js") != -1) { // If object is a js file
                    fileref=document.createElement('script')
                    fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
                    fileref.setAttribute("src", file);
                }
                else if (file.indexOf(".css") !=-1 ) { // If object is a css file
                    fileref=document.createElement("link")
                    fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
                    fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
                    fileref.setAttribute("href", file);
                }
            }
            if (fileref != "") {
                document.getElementsByTagName("head").item(0).appendChild(fileref)
                loadedobjects += file + " " // Remember this object as being already added to page
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried to use [jQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) instead? It might not solve the access issue, but it might make both coding and debugging easier.

Comment: I will do it once I figure out how to make these load!! Thanks for the suggestion.